# Empty request when sending special characters to API with Java

Tags: java, laravel, request

I'm using Java to send http requests to my API which is created using Laravel (5.4). If I send a request without any special characters it all works like a charm. But if there are any 'special' characters like: é, å, ö and such the request in Laravel is empty:

`dd(request()->all())` outputs `[]`

I guess this has to do with some wrong settings while creating the request in Java. I couldn't find a solution.

Here is the code responsible for creating the request.

```
public class HttpClient {

    org.apache.http.client.HttpClient client;

    public HttpClient() {
        client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    }

    public void post(String json) {
        try {
            HttpPost request = buildPostRequest(json);
            HttpResponse response = createClient().execute(request);

            int code = getStatusCode(response);

            if (code != 200) {
                throw new Exception("Error (" + code + ") on server.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private org.apache.http.client.HttpClient createClient() {
        return HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    }

    private HttpPost buildPostRequest(String json) throws Exception {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("some uri");
        request.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json);
        params.setContentEncoding("utf-8");
        params.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        request.setEntity(params);

        return request;
    }

    private int getStatusCode(HttpResponse response) {
        StatusLine line = response.getStatusLine();

        return line.getStatusCode();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Dump of the request before it get's send to the API.

[image: request dump]

Comment: It sounds like the issue is with the character encoding being sent from Java. Can you post a dump of the request being sent before it reaches the Laravel API?

Comment: @btl I added a screenshot. I also made a change to the code. Added the content type and encoding for the request `params` variable.

Comment: What does request->entity->content contain? Can you get a plain text dump of that? If not, my next step would be to hook up WireShark or Fiddler and see what is actually gettings transmitted over the wire.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem. In the `buildPostRequest()` method I changed from a `StringEntity` to a `ByteArrayEntity` and coverted the string to UTF-8 bytes.

```
ByteArrayEntity params = new ByteArrayEntity(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

If I send special characters to the API the request isn't empty anymore.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
 HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URLEncoder.encode("url here", "UTF-8"));
```